# Is there any way to start reading from specific position of an URL byte stream?

Tags: java, multithreading, java-stream, channel

My idea is to divide a big response text into small parts to load them concurrently.

The following code helps me open stream from an URL but I want to load its whole content from multithreads to optimize performance, then I will merge them into a single result. However, the method return a ReadableByteChannel which cannot specify the start position and I have to transfer it linearly:

```
URL url = new URL("link");
InputStream fromStream = url.openStream();
ReadableByteChannel fromChannel = Channels.newChannel(fromStream);
```

Is there any way to specify the position like SeekableByteChannel (seem likes this interface only works with file)? Thanks you :D

Comment: What's wrong with just reading and ignoring the part you don't want?

Comment: I want the whole content, but from many threads, then I will merge them into a single result.

Comment: The response from a single request is inherently serial.  There is no reason to think that using multiple threads just to read such a response should provide any benefit whatever.

Comment: my idea is to divide a big response text into small parts to load them concurrently. does it make sense?

Comment: The only way to accomplish that would be to split it up at the client side and send over multiple sockets, in which case you don't need to skip anything, each thread would only see its own fragment.  There is NO WAY to split up an incoming stream at the server and achieve any speedup.  As @JohnBollinger says, it is a serial stream.  If you want to split up _processing_, receive the entire stream into memory on one thread, then split it up and allocate to threads.  You cannot split up the ***reading*** of the stream.

Comment: Okay I got it, but can someone help me explain Vipul Gaur's answer on this post : https://www.quora.com/How-does-IDM-internet-download-manager-work-in-layman%E2%80%99s-terms

Comment: That is explained by the answer that you accepted.  (According to Vipul Gaur, the IDM is issuing a number of separate requests to download different chunks of the file using "Range" headers.)  It is unclear if this would actually help in your case.  There are to many "unknowns".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you can manipulate the request before it's a stream then yes, you would use the `Range` http header to specify the chunk of data you wanted...

See [Downloading a portion of a File using HTTP Requests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17643851/downloading-a-portion-of-a-file-using-http-requests)

If not then you will manually have to read past the data you don't need.

See [Given a Java InputStream, how can I determine the current offset in the stream?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/240294/given-a-java-inputstream-how-can-i-determine-the-current-offset-in-the-stream)

Comment: No problem, don't forget to mark as answer or ask for more clarification!

Comment: No problem, one is glad to be of service!

Comment: You mean `Range` -- although I've seen some HTTP requests for which `Rage` would indeed be suitable :-)